# Antonym for Claim

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I am looking for an antonym for the word *claim*.

The closest words I could find are  *reject*, *deny*, and, of course, *disclaim*. My problem with *disclaim* is that I have only ever seen it used as *disclaimer*, which has a rather special, almost legal, meaning in American English. My problem with *reject* and *deny* is that it sounds as though I am turning something down. They aren't necessarily opposite in meaning, and they convey an entirely different message.

If claim means...

> state or assert that something is the case

... then I am looking for

> not state or assert that something is the case, but not necessarily state that it *isn't* the case

Consider the following sentences:

1. I claim X.
2. I do not claim X.
3. I reject X.

I am looking to replace the "do not claim" in sentence number two.

Comment: My impression is that you don't need an antonym, the negative form of claim  can perfectly fit.

Comment: Indeed, just use 2. To claim something is a pretty specific action, why would those need an antonym? It's not likely that the language feels the need to produce a verb to describe something that people are _not_ doing most of the time - I can't think of an antonym for _scuba diving_ either.

Comment: You say you're looking for an antonym to *claim*, which would be its opposite, and then say you're looking for an equivalent to *not claim*, which is its absence/negation.

Comment: It is not often (in fact I can’t think of any English examples at all off the top of my head) that a language has a specific word for _not_ doing something. That is usually served by a simple negation, or a verb for doing the opposite (i.e., _claim_ <> _reject/refute/deny_). Similarly, there is no word for not rejecting that something is the case (but also not claiming that it is the case). The only exception I can call to mind is the negative copula or verb of existence in some languages (_değil-_ in Turkish, 没 _méi_ in Mandarin, 無い/ない _nai_ in Japanese, _ní_ in Irish, _e-_ in Finnish, etc.).

Comment: "not state or assert that something is the case, but not necessarily state that it isn't the case." Here, it appears that you're simply abstaining

Comment: In my opinion if you are looking for "do not claim", you are *not* looking for an *antonym*. Probably you should change your question's title. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_(semantics)

Comment: @HonzaZidek Not every concept is represented in binary. Antonym means "a word opposite in meaning to another". *Not claim* is an opposite of *claim*. *Claim* has many antonyms, and I simply want the one with the least "extra baggage".

Comment: When I was an undergraduate, the maths students used to argue with the computer science students about whether the opposite of "all the pawns on the board are white" was (CS) "all the pawns on the board are black" or (M) "at least one of the pawns on the board is not white". The mathematicians were using logical opposite, while the computer scientists were using polar opposite.

Comment: @AndrewC That's wrong (and I'm going to guess the part about CS students is fiction). A CS student will tell you that the logical opposite of *"all the pawns on the board are white"* is *"it is not the case that all the pawns on the board are white"*. Discrete Mathematics and Foundations of Mathematics (or some variant thereof) are a part of nearly every computer science curriculum. Trust me, we understand where to put the "not" in a sentence. The safe place is always to prepend *"It is not the case that... "* to the statement.

Comment: @Rusher I _did_ not make this story up - it was the subject of lengthy heated debate. It was in the second year, and the closest thing to a discrete mathematics CS unit was an optional second year unit called formal methods, which touched a little on set theory but hardly at all on logic, which is probably why they struggled more with functional programming and argued with the mathematicians about the meaning of the word opposite. However, on the CS side of the argument, it's fair to say that the mathematicians should have been using the more correct term "negation" instead of "opposite".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"waiver" comes to my mind. I presume you mean "claim" in a legal sense.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waiver) "A waiver is the voluntary relinquishment or surrender of some known right or privilege."

Verb: [to waive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/waive): "to refrain from claiming or insisting on"

Comment: The question clearly states that he is talking about _claim_ in the sense “state or assert that something is the case”. For that sense, _waive_ is not an antonym. You cannot waive that something is the case. _Waive_ only works as an antonym in the sense “lay claim to”.

Comment: "claim" vs. "dispute"/"contest"

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The example you gave, *"You cannot waive that something is the case."*, makes no sense. You can't just stick an antonym in the definition of its counterpart and call it poor. *"I waive victory."*, *"I waive my inheritance."*, and *"I waive my rights."* all make plenty of sense. The sense of rejection and denial is almost negligible when I read it out loud. I also like that waive is an action rather than a lack thereof. I'll let the question stew for a few days to see what others think before I accept anything.

Comment: @Rusher Your comment makes little sense to me. For an antonym to be an antonym, it should fit the same semantic scope, except with the opposite meaning [as ill-defined a notion as that is]. For the meaning of _claim_ that you gave (which is fundamentally different from the one in ‘claim victory/an inheritance/my rights’), _waive_ does not work as an antonym. It works fine as an antonym for “I claim my rights to this land”, but not for “I claim that 3 + 5 = 13 in the Fourth Dimension”—and the latter is the sense that you specified in the question, not the former.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I provided a semantic scope via the examples at the bottom of my post, but you chose to ignore it in favor of creating your own semantic scope in which the word does *not* work. You are correct that plopping the definition of the word into a random sentence, like "I state or assert victory." makes very little sense, but "I state or assert that I was victorious." works just fine. I disagree that an antonym must fit *perfectly* into *every* scope in which its counterpart *could be* used. I'm not sure I understand the point of generating senseless material.

Comment: @Rusher The semantic scope you provided, through a dictionary definition (one of several possible), was: “not state or assert that something is the case, but not necessarily state that it _isn't_ the case”. I never said an antonym must fit _every_ scope; but this one doesn’t fit ***the scope that you (the asker) specifically provided***. I did not “ignore it in favor of creating [my] own semantic scope”, I used the one you gave _verbatim_. If that is not the [only] scope you’re looking for, you should edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You seem to be confusing scope with definition. If you want to use the word in a ***sentence***, then the ***sentence*** provided is clearly *"I _____ X."* If you want to use the ***definition***, then I also provided that. If you want to use ***the word in the definition***, then more power to you, but it won't make any sense. It is simply not the case than any antonym can replace the first noun you find in the definition of its counterpart.

Comment: The sentence “I claim X” would be equally valid for _any_ definition, sense, or scope of the verb. When you quote one, and only one, definition of the verb, and then say that what you need is a verb that means XYZ related to that definition, you cannot be surprised if people think that is the definition of the verb you want. Also, ‘scope’ (short for ‘semantic scope’) is a perfectly valid word to use for the, well, _scope_ that any given definition or sense of a word has. The sentence structure you provided is the _context_, not the scope.

Comment: You can use "I waive citizenship" to contrast with "I claim citizenship", because citizenship is a noun, and waive means let go of, whereas in _this_ context, claim means demand, not assert. It makes much less sense to say "I waive that x > 5" because you can't release or let go of "that x>5" any more than you can demand that x>5.

Comment: Oh, this reminds me of [Vroomfondel's demands](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6LgGIvmSce0C&pg=PT140&lpg=PT140&dq=Vroomfondel+%22we+demand+admission%22&source=bl&ots=up6-V5xe1a&sig=KKFB0erEL4Cplv9dYhXGYa82lFM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dSuRU-PSOqq80QXj2oDgAg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Vroomfondel%20%22we%20demand%20admission%22&f=false), which are funny because he uses _demand_ in place of _assert_.

Comment: @AndrewC You *can* assert that you are a citizen. I don't know where demand came form. "I demand citizenship." is not even close to "I claim citizenship."

Comment: @Rusher Indeed - because "I am a citizen" is a factual statement, which can be asserted or denied. "I waive my citizenship" works but "I waive that I am a citizen" doesn't.

Comment: @AndrewC I still don't understand what point you are trying to make. You just admitted that the word waive *does* work in "I waive my citizenship.", and then you generated yet another sentence where it does not work. Are you trying to say that waive is a poor antonym because it doesn't fit in that particular sentence? One poorly constructed sentence is not proof that a word is not an antonym. If I sound like a broken record, it is only because you keep repeating "I are gud at making sentence. Therefore, not waive is not an antonym." over and over.

Comment: @Rusher It's not an antonym in the sense/sentences you gave in your question: _"If claim means state or assert that something is the case I am looking for: not state or assert that something is the case, but not necessarily state that it isn't the case"_ In this sense of the word claim (assert), waive is not an antonym, because you cannot waive that something is the case. To allow waive as an answer, ask _"If claim means assert your rights to something you feel you deserve, own or desire, I am looking for: fail to assert your rights, but not necessarily deny that you have the rights."_

Comment: @Rusher For example, if you said _"If cross means move from one side of something to another, I'm looking for a word that means to move back to the original side"_ and someone answered with _tick_, I'd argue that _tick_ isn't an antonym in the sense of the question, because you can't tick a river or a road. Claim has more than one meaning, and the one specified in your question isn't an antonym of waive, because you can't waive that something is the case. The examples I gave are all ones involving (not) claiming that something is the case, as asked in your question.

Comment: @Rusher In your question, "claim" has a specified meaning _related_ to "say", whereas in this answer it has a different meaning, more related to "take" or "get" or "hold". A good answer to the question _as asked_ should be related in meaning to "don't say" but shouldn't be related in meaning to "release". Waive _is_ directly related in meaning to "release" and "drop", not to "don't say".

Comment: @AndrewC I can't generate a sentence where tick and road are related in a way that means "not travel across", and so I would agree that tick is a poor antonym in that context. But I *can* transform ***"I waive that I am a citizen."*** into ***"I waive citizenship."***. I think that we can agree to disagree on the following basis: You think that the two sentences in bold convey a completely different idea. I believe they convey the same idea. We simply disagree about whether the transformation takes the word out of the context I provided, and that's the end of the story.

Comment: @Rusher I can transform __I tick the road__ to __I tick "The road"__, which makes perfect sense.

Comment: I didn't say they convey a completely different idea - the two sentences (one nonsensical, the other valid) convey a very similar idea, it's just that the first one genuinely doesn't work, so waive is not an antonym for the assert meaning of claim.

Comment: @Rusher If you want antonyms of _either_ meaning of claim, I think you should edit the question to include the other meaning you want to allow. It seems to me that either you don't accept that claim has two different meanings (which is why I've tried to persuade you that it has) or you think it's OK for answers to ignore the specified meaning and reinterpret/transform the word into another context to get an antonym (which is why I suggest you edit the question to allow either).

Comment: @Rusher I propose another way we could agree, if you only ever want to claim that you had some right or other, with examples like "I claim that I have citizenship" and "I claim you should give me my money back" and "I claim I have immunity from prosecution": If you give these examples in the question of how you want to use the word, this answer becomes an insightful way of cutting out the red-herring factual assertion meaning in the definition.

Comment: @Rusher In what actual context had you wanted the word? What did you want to fail to claim originally? Adding this to your question could settle the argument.

Comment: @AndrewC I am not changing the context (which is *clearly* listed in the question) until I am convinced that the current context is unreasonable. We disagree that the given context accurately fits the antonym "waive". The reason we disagree is that you feel it must fit *perfectly*, while I allow for a *small transformation* (as long as the original meaning is well-preserved). You *did* agree that the meaning of my transformation conveyed a mostly similar idea, but then claimed that the very existence of the nonsensical sentence meant that waive was not an antonym. That's a non sequiter.

Comment: @Rusher Imagine you asked "If _right_ means that something is a good thing to do, I want a single word that says that something is not right, that I can use in _X is not right_." and someone answered _false_, I would point out that it doesn't fit the definition given, because it doesn't work in "Overcharging is false.", you would say that's irrelevant because it works in "Saying that the earth orbits the moon is false.", and that you can make a small transformation from "Overcharging is false" to "Overcharging is false accounting."

Comment: @AndrewC By your logic, sentences that do not work are a counterexample to the validity of the entire English language. By my logic, the existence of sentences that *do* work are a testament to the validity of the entire English language. Whose way of thinking is correct?

Comment: @Rusher Can you read my example of false vs right? Do you think false is an antonym of right in the context I gave, or does the question or answer need to be different to allow it?

Comment: I am unable to construct an appropriate sentence using the word false as an antonym in that context. However, I *am* able to find an appropriate sentence using waive as an antonym in the context that *I* gave. Therefore, I find your analogy to be inappropriate.

Comment: @Rusher Nono, I _was_ able to find an antonym to right using the word false in that context - I used "Overcharging is false accounting.", just like you were able to find your antonym. What's the problem? It's only a _small_ transformation, and clearly preserves the meaning of "Overcharging is false."

Comment: @AndrewC I transformed citizenship into its meaning, "a state of being a citizen". You added the word "accounting", which *drastically* changes the meaning of the sentence. But maybe you are on to something! Let's say that the original sentence looks like, "Overcharging is accounting that is not right." Now I agree that "false" can be used as an antonym of "right" with only a small transformation.

Comment: @Rusher "Overcharging is false pricing."?

Comment: @Rusher but in any case we're switching from the moral correctness meaning of _right_ to the factual correctness meaning, which contradicts the definition of "right means that something is a good thing to do" in the question. To allow false as an antonym, surely we need to rewrite the definition to remove the moral aspect?

Comment: @AndrewC Are you saying that accounting is a fact, and so "false accounting" is an incorrect fact? That doesn't even make sense, and so that is not the way I understood your sentence. I understood "false accounting" to mean *bad*, *evil*, or *unjust* accounting. If you were to convince me that I misunderstood you, then I would go back to thinking false cannot be used as an antonym. I imagine that you would then have a problem with that, and you would revert to using my own logic to convince me that it *is* an antonym.

Comment: @Rusher That actually made me laugh, and perhaps first persuading you one thing in order to persuade you the opposite is unproductive!

Comment: @Rusher In essence I feel that all the examples where _waive_ works unmodified, "I waive my rights", "I waive the fee", "We waive the ban" all disagree with the definition in the question "assert that something is the case" (instead using assertion/releasing of a right/rule). Conversely, for all the examples that fit the assertion-about-facts definition, eg "I claim Obama is more right wing than Cameron", "I claim that it was irresponsible", "I claim miles are better than km", the word _waive_ doesn't fit.

Comment: There _is_ a difference in meaning between "I claim a free bar of chocolate" (where you _don't_ currently have it, but have reason to think you should, opposite: "I waive the chocolate"), and "I claim that I have a free bar of chocolate" (where you _do_ already have it, opposite: "I don't (say I) have the chocolate"). Similarly you can say "I claim citizenship" on arrival, waiving your birth certificate, but if you say "I claim that I'm a citizen" you'd better already have those citizenship papers handy.

Comment: @AndrewC On second thought, comment retracted. I think we are destined to repeat this discussion for all eternity, or simply agree to disagree (which we really should have done forever ago, since we both know that arguing linguistics is **subjective** anyway).

Comment: You can waive citizenship, but you can't waive that you are a citizen or that you have chocolate.

Comment: @Rusher OK, let's agree to disagree as you say - thanks for making me laugh anyway.

Comment: ...and of course, any suggestion I made that someone might waive a free bar of chocolate, whilst grammatically OK is clearly foolish to the point of absurdity! :)

Answer (score 2):

How about the phrase "I am agnostic about X"? I think that might fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

The antonym for claim in contexts where to claim would imply some kind of relationship with, or ownership of, the object is [**disavow**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disavow).

> 1:  to deny responsibility for
>
> 2:  to refuse to acknowledge or accept

A classic example usage of this word with meaning 1 is when a government 'disavows' spies or special forces troops that have been captured in foreign territory they shouldn't have been operating in.

An example of meaning 2 might be a medieval lord disavowing his first or second born son for wanting to join the clergy instead of becoming a squire. (Going to the clergy is supposedly the 3rd son's role).

other possible words for consideration include:

[repudiate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/repudiate) - refuse to accept, deny the validity of (has use in legal contexts that may be more specific)

and [disclaim](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disclaim) - refuse to acknowledge, deny

Comment: **disown** is similar to **disavow**.

Comment: @Scott agreed. I think disown is perhaps narrower in scope than disavow, because you have to own something to disown it, whereas disavowing something, as I understand it, can be done if there is any connection at all.

Answer (score 0):

How about *suppose*?

If you suppose something, you do not state or assert that something is the case, but also not state or assert that it is not.

Answer (score 0):

A claim is an attestation (valid or not) or to give witness. An antonym of 'to attest' is

> **[Estoppel by silence](http://law.academic.ru/1299/estoppel_by_silence)**
>       A type of estoppel that prevents someone from asserting something when that person had both the duty and the opportunity to speak up earlier, and his or her silence put another person at a disadvantage.